# Resourse overwritting warning

Tags: android

I always get a resource overwriting warning when I want to create a layout file BUT in different folder (for different configuration). I created a folder in lib directory as layout-port (for portrait orientation) and after right clicking the very same folder,If i wanna create a new file with the name of default xml layout file, it gives me the "file overwriting warning". WHY IS THAT? As far as I know I can use same file name in different resource folder.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this annoying situation too, it seems that even you selected `layout-land` to create the new file there, it still defaults to `layout`, so my workaround is to create the new file with a different name, for example `main1.xml`. Then I cut/paste the file from `layout`, into the `layout-land`.

Comment: Instead I manually put the file into the directory-layout-port in project workspace. But is it really a problem/bug in eclipse ? There's on more weird problem, sometimes if I double click a file, instead of opening, it move/jumps to another folder.